# input validation in vb 2013 input box string conversion error

Tags: vb.net

*My program crashes when I enter letter characters into the input box or leave the input box blank. Why is my validation if statement not working?*

```
Option Strict On
Public Class frmPickUpSticks
Dim playersTurn As Boolean = False
Dim remainingSticks As Integer 'count sticks
Dim losses As Integer = 0 'count player losses
Private Sub btnNewGame_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNewGame.Click
    lblOutput.Text = ""
    remainingSticks = CInt(InputBox("How many matchsticks would you like (5 - 25)?", "Pick Number of Matches!"))
    'Validate input
    If IsNumeric(remainingSticks) Then
        If (remainingSticks >= 5) And (remainingSticks <= 25) Then
            DisplayMatches()
            If (remainingSticks Mod 4 = 1) Then
                MessageBox.Show("You go first!")
                playersTurn = True
                turns()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("I go first.")
                turns()
            End If
        Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number between 5 and 25.")
    End If
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Input must be numeric.", "Input Error")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't automatically take what your user types in an InputBox and pass this input to any function or method that expects a number for input. The InputBox method has been designed to return a string and this string need to be converted but you need to use methods that know how to parse a string. Otherwise methods that are not designed to handle nonnumeric values (CInt) will cause exceptions.

Instead you should try some kind of parsing and the NET Library offers many tools to use. In your case the correct one is [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Dim remainingSticks As Integer
Dim userInput = InputBox("How many matchsticks .....")
If Int32.TryParse(userInput, remainingSticks) Then
   .... ok your remainingStick contains the converted value
Else
   MessageBox.Show("You should type a valid integer number between 5-25")
```

The Int32.TryParse will look at your input string and try to convert to a valid integer value. If it succeed then the second parameter contains the converted integer and returns True, if it fails it return false and your second parameter will have the default value of zero.

Of course after a succesfull conversion to an integer your don't need anymore a check with IsNumeric

Answer (score 0):

You should use a string variable in the inputbox

dim st as string

st = InputBox("How many matchsticks would you like (5 - 25)?", "Pick Number of Matches!"))

remainingSticks = val(st)

. . .

Comment: `Val` will throw an exception if the number is so big that cannot be converted to an Integer. Besides, it is time to forget all those VB6 compatibility functions still around in 2016

Comment: lol@forget vb6 compatibility . . . I can't help myself i come from a POWERBASIC age , , ,